# PHP Get contents of webpage

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

So I am using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to get the contents of a webpage. After I knew what I was doing was right, I still got the error that there was nothing to be found.

So here's what I am using to see if there is anything actually being caught:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$first_url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/chinese-super-league/startseite/wettbewerb_CSL.html"; // works

$html = file_get_html($first_url);
echo "<textarea>Output\n===========\n $html</textarea><br /><br />";

$second_url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/chinese-super-league/torschuetzen/wettbewerb_CSL.html"; // does not work?

$html = file_get_html($second_url);
echo "<textarea>Output\n===========\n $html</textarea><br />";
?>
```

No errors. Nothing in the 2nd textarea. The second URL does not seem to be getting scraped bt the tool... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`simple_php_dom.php` contains:

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
...
if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
{
    return false;
}
```

The second page is over 672000 bytes, so this size check fails. Increase that constant and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your question it's working fine. You have to check the php memory limit it's may be the problem

increase your PHP memory limit and try again

```
<?php 

//use this to increase memory limit
ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');

$second_url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/chinese-super-league/torschuetzen/wettbewerb_CSL.html"; // does not work?

$html = file_get_contents($second_url);
echo "<textarea>Output\n===========\n $html</textarea><br />";
```

Comment: You're calling `file_get_contents`, not `file_get_html`.

Comment: it's not a PHP function. you should add that file_get_html

Comment: verify this constant define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000); this will block your request if it's more than mentioned size this constant exist inside the simple dom library

Comment: It's part of the Simple HTML DOM Parser library that he loaded.