# Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /home/admin/web//public_html/index.php on line 14

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /home/admin/web//public_html/index.php on line 14

Why does it fail?

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/facebook');

$title = $html->find('h1[id=firstHeading]',0)->innertext; 

echo $title;
```

Comment: $html var is not an object. check what file_get_html returns!

Comment: Your `file_get_html()` function has failed to execute.

Comment: Different page works;  

example  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/apple

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579258/php-get-contents-of-webpage/16579511#16579511 for a possible reason

Comment: Simple HTML DOM's default size limit is 600K, that page is 800K. Increase the limit as described in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with file_get_html but it probably returns false on errors, so you should check the returned value:

```
if ($html === false) {
   // check what the error is (look for file_get_html documentation to understand how to get more info on the error
} else {
   // file is ok, process it
}
```

Comment: `file_get_html()` is part of the popular Simple HTML DOM parser library.